# How do I connect to a Wi-Fi network from a Kali Linux live USB?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, kali-linux

I am on a MacBook Pro and my primary operating system is macOS. When I am on macOS, I am fully able to browse the internet and connect to Wi-Fi networks, but when running a Kali Linux live USB, I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi. The network name appears, and when I click on it, I am prompted to enter a password, but then it continues to prompt me to enter a password and never actually connects me to the network. My friend suggested I purchase a USB Wi-Fi adapter, but I believe you need to use `sudo apt` to install the drivers for them, which requires internet access in the first place, and I do not know of any adapters that are automatically supported by Kali that don't require drivers to be installed. **TL;DR:** I can't connect to Wi-Fi networks on my Kali Linux live USB, even though I can use the internet fine on my main OS, so I don't think it is an issue with my Wi-Fi card. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307028/100397

Comment: This is slightly different for me. When I ran `iwconfig` in the Kali terminal, I saw `en0` as an interface option, but it also said `no wireless extensions.`

Comment: MartinMcWatters did you install Kali onto the physical hardware or as a virtual machine?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287789/100397